# sql и python запрос

Tags: python, sql

Не могу понять, что не так в запросе. db_name Это как схема с кучей разных табличек. Мне нужна db_name = films с таблицей Films. Я сохранил films.db в текущей директории. Но не могу получить вывод запроса.

```
import sqlite3

def author(db_name):
    con = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    result = con.execute("SELECT title FROM 'db_name'.Films WHERE year=1997").fetchall()
    con.close()
    result = [x[0] for x in result]
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = author(input())
    print("\n".join(results))
```

Comment: Одинарная кавычка в SQLite однозначно говорит, что находящееся внутри есть строковый литерал. Тогда как на этом месте должно быть имя объекта (таблицы). Запомните - в SQL любая кавычка имеет своё назначение, и они не взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 1):

Можете подставить переменную в строку с помощью f-строки:

```py
result = con.execute(f"SELECT title FROM {db_name}.Films WHERE year=1997").fetchall()
                     ^                   ^       ^
```